# how to differentiate the integral with singularity

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$${d\over dx} \, \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t \, \sqrt{t^2-x^2}} \, dt $$

How to move the derivative into the integral or simplify?

Comment: Hint: if you write $g(x_1,x_2) = \int_a^{x_1} f(t,x_2)\,\mathrm d t$, then $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} g(x,x) = \partial_1 g + \partial_2 g$, hence
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_a^x f(t,x)\,\mathrm d t =  f(x,x) + \int_a^x \partial_x f(t,x)\,\mathrm d t.
$$
Is that enough for you to continue?

Comment: Statement is confusing - too many x's.  Should it be dt not dx?

Comment: It must be
$${d\over dx}\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t\sqrt {t^2-x^2}} \color{red}{dt} $$

Comment: yes, it should be dt

Comment: but f(x,x) = inf?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Leibniz integral rule,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \, x} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) \, dt = f(x, b(x)) \, \frac{d b}{d x} - f(x, a(x)) \, \frac{d a}{d x} + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{d f(x, t)}{dx} \, dt, $$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{d I}{d x} &= 
{d\over dx} \, \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t \, \sqrt{t^2-x^2}} \, dt \\
&= - \lim_{t \to x} \frac{e^{-t}}{t \, \sqrt{t^2 - x^2}} + x \, \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t} \, (t^2 - x^2)^{-3/2} \, dt. 
\end{align}
The derivative then becomes a problem with the limit as $t \to x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\totald{}{x}\int_{x}^{\infty}
{\expo{-t} \over t\root{t^{2} - x^{2}}}\,\dd t} =
\totald{}{x}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-t -\ x} \over
\pars{t + x}\root{t^{2} + 2xt}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\LARGE\color{red}{\S}}{=} &
\int_{0}^{\infty}\partiald{}{x}
\bracks{{\expo{-x -\ t} \over
\pars{x + t}\root{t^{2} + 2xt}}}\,\dd t
\end{align}
$\ds{\large\color{red}{\S}}$: Can you make this step ?.